# How to keep a System.Timers.Timer stopped during ElapsedEvent

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, locking, system.timers.timer

I am using **System.Timers.Timer** and every x seconds I need to perform some tasks in an ElapsedEvent method. While I am performing my tasks in the ElapsedEvent method, I want the timer to be stopped. However, I have another method that can start the timer, which can be called while the ElapsedEvent is running. My code looks something like this:

```
class MyClass {
   Timer myTimer;

   public MyClass {
      myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
      // init timer code here...
   }

   public void ElapsedEventTask(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
      myTimer.Enabled = false;
      try
      {
          // do my tasks
      }
      catch
      {
         ...
      }
      finally
      {
         myTimer.Enabled = true;
      }
   }
}

public void AnotherMethod() {
   // do some things
   myTimer.Enabled = true;
}
```

How do I prevent `AnotherMethod` from starting the timer while I'm completing the task in `ElapsedEventTask`?

Comment: Is the `AnotherMethod` method intended to be called only once, to start the timer the first time, or you also have a method that stops the timer, so that the timer can be started and stopped manually multiple times?

Comment: `AnotherMethod` can be called multiple times, and there is another method to stop the timer. So yes, `myTimer` can be started and stopped manually multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a variable that indicate if the task is running. Finaly to be thread safe, you need to use `lock` when this variable is used in with `myTimer.Enabled` :

```cs
class MyClass
{
    object syncEnableRunning = new object();
    bool running
    Timer myTimer;

    public void ElapsedEventTask(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        lock(syncEnableRunning)
        {
            running = true;
            myTimer.Enabled = false;
        }
        
        try { /*do my tasks*/}
        catch { ... }
        finally
        {
            lock(syncEnableRunning)
            {
                myTimer.Enabled = true;
                running = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void AnotherMethod()
    {
        // do some things
        lock(syncEnableRunning)
        {
            if(!running)
            {
                myTimer.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that the use of `volatile` is enough to ensure thread-safety here. It is possible that the method `AnotherMethod` will be invoked on the thread A before the `Elapsed` event ticks on the thread B, but an OS-level thread switch will occur during the `AnotherMethod` invocation, and the thread A will execute the `myTimer.Enabled = true;` line after the same property has been set to `false` by the thread B. To make it thread-safe you need to introduce a proper `lock` IMHO.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, totaly agree... Shame on me. Thank for your sugestion, I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer#thread-safety) the `System.Timers.Timer` class is not thread-safe, so it's not safe to touch its `Enabled` property from multiple threads without synchronization (doing so results to undefined behavior). Vernou's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67330671/11178549) shows how to synchronize the threads by using locks, but personally I am a bit nervous with trying to enforce a non-overlapping execution policy using a mechanism that apparently was designed to be re-entrant. So my suggestion is to ditch the `System.Timers.Timer`, and use instead an asynchronous loop, controlled by Stephen Cleary's `PauseTokenSource` mechanism:

```
class MyClass
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts;
    private readonly PauseTokenSource _pts;
    public Task Completion { get; private set; }

    public MyClass(TimeSpan interval)
    {
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _pts = new PauseTokenSource();
        _pts.IsPaused = true;
        Completion = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    await _pts.Token.WaitWhilePausedAsync(_cts.Token);
                    var delayTask = Task.Delay(interval, _cts.Token);
                    /* Do my tasks */
                    await delayTask;
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
                when (_cts.IsCancellationRequested) { } // Ignore
        });
    }

    public void Start() => _pts.IsPaused = false;
    public void Stop() => _pts.IsPaused = true;
    public void Complete() => _cts.Cancel();
}
```

The [`PauseTokenSource`](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/5.0.0/netstandard2.0/doc/Nito.AsyncEx.PauseTokenSource) is the controller of a [`PauseToken`](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/5.0.0/netstandard2.0/doc/Nito.AsyncEx.PauseToken), a similar concept with the [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource)/`CancellationToken` combo. The difference is that the `CancellationTokenSource` can be canceled only once, while the `PauseTokenSource` can be paused/unpaused multiple times. This class is included in the [AsyncEx.Coordination](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/) package.

The `MyClass` exposes a `Complete` method that terminates the asynchronous loop, and a `Completion` property that can be awaited. It is a good idea to `await` this property before closing the program, to give to any active operation the chance to complete. Otherwise the process may be killed in the middle of a background execution, with unpredictable consequences.

Comment: This appears way more complicated than it needs to be.  Where does the concept of multiple threads come in?  The OP is using a single thread, and the problem is he doesn't want the timer to tick a 2nd time before the first one is finished.   There's no multi-threading/tasks involved in his example.

Comment: @Neil it's an asynchronous loop controlled by tokens. A loop provides the non-overlapping guarantee that the OP is searching for, in a obvious way. It is logically impossible for two consecutive iterations to run in parallel. Each iteration may run on a different thread, but it will not start before the completion of the previous iteration. A thread-switch may occur at the `await` points, but it's not obligatory. If the `ThreadPool` has low demand and has created only one thread, all iterations will run on that same thread.

Comment: @Neil regarding this solution being overly complicated, it would be a fair argument in case an alternative solution was available, that offered the same behavioral guarantees, while being less complicated. Vernou's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67330671/11178549) *may* produce the desirable behavior, but I would not be able to guarantee it without studying first thoroughly the source code of the `System.Timers.Timer` class, and convincing myself that it will behave desirably even in extreme conditions of extended `ThreadPool` saturation. Which is considerably more complicated IMHO.

Answer (score -1):

I would create a one shot timer, which you then need to start again at the end of your timer function.

```
myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
myTimer.AutoReset = false;


public void ElapsedEventTask(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
  ...
  finally
  {
     myTimer.Start();
  }
```

}